# Unable to provide password for private with WinSCP command line in Windows 2008 R2

Tags: script, sftp, winscp

I am following the example at https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting to automate the transfer of files from my PC to an SFTP server. However each time I try to provide a password for private key, it fails to authenticate.

I am able to use the same password when using the WinSCP graphical user interface and when I explicitly type the password in the command line however not when I automate.

My code looks as follows

```
open sftp://user:password%21@example.com
```

I have followed the suggestion at https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url to encode special characters hence the %21 which symbolizes an exclamation mark. Interestingly enough the example on the page does not encode the exclamation mark e.g. `4pRte!ai%253@example.com`

I have also tried using `password!` and that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that it was expecting a password phrase for a private key which WinSCP doesn't support providing programmatically as per the FAQ at https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_passphrase.

The way around it was to use the Pageant agent that is provided with the WinSCP installation or as a standalone executable at https://winscp.net/eng/download.php. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It's not "password", it's "passphrase".

As per WinSCP FAQ [How can I connect without entering private key passphrase each time?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_passphrase):

> **Automating Private Key Authentication**
>   You can specify the passphrase using [`-passphrase`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open#passphrase) switch of [`open`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open) command in scripting

Example:

```
open -passphrase=... -privatekey=... sftp://user@example.com/
```